# Firefox Network Tab shows wrong image size

Tags: firefox

What does Size mean the in Firefox Network Tab?

I expected to see the actual image size here, but for some reason FF shows 1.4 Mb for 4.8 Mb image.

I checked the same image in [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com) to ensure that this is not a connection problem and got 4.8 Mb as expected.

Image from deviantart:
http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/082/a/0/flying_jellyfish_wallpaper_by_andrework-d7bcloj.jpg

Firefox Network Tab
[image: Firefox Network Tab]

HTTP Debugger
[image: HTTP Debugger]